# JavaScript - recursive setInterval calls the parent function twice - why?

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-leaks, setinterval

I have this simple piece of code in the head of the HTML5 doc:

```
var lol = 0;

function madeMyDay() {
  lol++;
  console.log(lol);
  setInterval(madeMyDay, 1000);
}
```

The function is first time called from this:

```
<script>
  madeMyDay();
</script>
```

after some div - to run it just after the div loads, and not waiting for the whole document.

What I am expecting is to see the following:

```
1 (at start)
2 (after 1 sec)
3 (after 2 sec)
4 (after 3 sec)
...
```

But I get:

```
1  (at start)
2  (after 1 sec)
3  (after 2 sec)
4  (after 2 sec, together with 3)
5  (after 3 sec)
6  (after 3 sec, together with 5)
7  (after 3 sec, together with 5)
8  (after 3 sec, together with 5)
9  (after 4 sec)
10 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
11 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
12 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
13 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
14 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
15 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
16 (after 4 sec, together with 9)
...
```

This of course makes browser crash due to memory leak in a few minutes (if not dozens of seconds).

It looks like setInterval calls the parent function twice - I have no idea why and how to prevent this odd behavior?

I tried the setTimeout - it does the job correctly. What is the magic in setInterval, that I don't understand?

PS. - tested on recent Chrome on Kubuntu

Comment: A single call to setInterval() repeats until you call clearInterval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change setInterval to setTimeout

```
function madeMyDay() {
  lol++;
  console.log(lol);
  setTimeout(madeMyDay, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use setTimeout() because it only calls the function once.

That allows you to do the recursive bit to keep it going.

Otherwise, setInterval() repeats the function call on the interval, so a single call of

```
setInterval(function () {console.log(Date.now()), 1000);
```

will repeat every second.

**EDIT:** to show you how setInterval() works, this is also a valid fix to your problem:

```
var lol = 0;

setInterval(madeMyDay, 1000);

function madeMyDay() {
  lol++;
  console.log(lol);
}
```

Notice there is no recursion here. setInterval() does the repeating.

Comment: Oh, that's the magic... So I did not understand the setInterval correctly, thank you!

Comment: As you can see both can be used. It's easier to stop the loop by conditionally breaking the recursion in the setTimeout() version than storing the result of setInterval() and using it with clearInterval(), in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done just before your answer, but still had no idea that setInterval repeats all the time... Thank you for this clarification!

Comment: No prob. You can check this as the solution too, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You Could check if the interval has already been defined before setting it.

```
var lol = 0;

function madeMyDay() {
  lol++;
  console.log(lol);
  if(typeof myInterval == "undefined") {
    var myInterval = setInterval(madeMyDay, 1000);
  }
}
```